# $V(X^m + Y^m - Z^m)$ (projective Fermat curve) isomorphic to projective line iff $m=1, 2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I've convinced myself that the projective Fermat curve $V(X^m + Y^m - Z^m) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is isomorphic to a projective line if and only if $m =1$ or $m = 2$, but I'm not sure how to prove this fact.

Are there proofs of this fact available online? Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: You can calculate the genus easily from the degree.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the explicit isomorphisms in the case when $m = 1$ or $m = 2$. Then if $m \geq 3$ you could use the [degree genus formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula), since the Fermat curves are smooth, to see that the genus of the Fermat curves for $m \geq 3$ is at least $1$, but any projective line has genus $0$.

Off course, you also need to know that two isomorphic curves have the same genus.